# How to pass link query params to deeplink using Branch.io

Tags: branch.io

Is it possible to create a branch link that receives a query param, and then use this parameters as a path param to the deeplink passed to the app?

Example:

- Branch link - something.app.link/something_else?id=1
- Deeplink configuration inside branch panel (ex: $ios_deeplink_path): myapp://something_else/**:id**

Would this be possible (having this dynamic :id parameter)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your use case is to create dynamic links then definitely it is possible. If you would like to append custom data to one of the [Quick Links](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/create-quick-links) you can do it in the following way -

```
https://your.app.link/fzmLEhobLD?content_id=123
```

For long links which can be created without network calls to Branch, you can have something like this -

```
https://your.app.link/fzmLEhobLD?foo=bar&baz=456&$fallback_url=https%3A%2F%2Fbranch.io%2F
```

Similarly a dynamic long link would be -

```
https://your.app.link/?foo=bar&baz=456&$fallback_url=https%3A%2F%2Fbranch.io%2F
```

You can reference the following Branch Documents for all above examples -

https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/creating-a-deep-link#section-create-deep-links

https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/creating-a-deep-link#section-long-links

Comment: Kartik, thanks for answering... But is still not clear to me how then I would use content_id in the deeplink created... How do I pass the "123" to the deeplink path? Example: myapp://content/123?

Comment: You can have something like - `deeplink_path=content/123`. Also, you don't need to append URI scheme in your deep link path as Branch automatically appends it.

Comment: Kartik... but if I do ```deeplink_path=content/123``` I am hardcoding the link to this id... My ideia would be to user whatever id was passed on the original link (?contentId=XXX) on the deeplink_path --> ```deeplink_path=content/XXX```

Comment: any chance you've seen the comment above?

Comment: @RamonCanales passing in query param in the URI scheme is not possible. Since you can already attach custom data to your deep links we don't support query params for URI schemes. Please reference the link examples shared in the above answer.

Comment: This still doesn't restrict you from creating dynamic links or passing in a deep link path. If you need more help I'd recommend you to drop a mail to support@branch.io

Comment: Thanks... In the end I just wanted to confirm if it wasn't really possible... We can handle with the extra params inside the app then. Regards